# I tried mounting drive to collab as follows. Changed the root directory. Yet it says file not found in the next step. What is going wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, directory

I'm attaching the python code below.Image description below:

[image]

Comment: Can you please write the code here, instead of an image?

Comment: Sure! @KetZoomer
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

root_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/Convolution_Dataset/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

Comment: Could you put that in your answer?